# pyvirtualdisplay errors on stdout FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm running a Docker container on Azure and using pyvirtualdisplay to open a display for rendering. After doing

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=False, size=(1400, 900))
display.start()
```

I get the following error. Any tips?

```
  File "/code/.../scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=False, size=(1400, 900))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 63, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 50, in __init__
    manage_global_env=manage_global_env,
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 88, in __init__
    helptext = get_helptext(program)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/util.py", line 10, in get_helptext
    p.call()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 141, in call
    self.start().wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 219, in wait
    self._wait4process()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/ic2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 250, in _wait4process
    self.stdout = self._stdout_file.read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Also, I've installed xvfb with this in my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install xvfb mesa-utils -y \
        && apt install freeglut3-dev -y
```

Comment: When does the error occur? Could you show your `Dockerfile`

Comment: The docker container is pre-built. A python script launches a job on Azure that pulls from DockerHub https://hub.docker.com/layers/himty/ic2docker/latest/images/sha256-76200c1ea3b926f2291051373ebc1b74fddba7058a8a4f9dca8407e541413adc?context=repo and starts up this python script. If it's worth anything, does `import logging; log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` affect this tempfile's location?